# How to get plain text from html in laravel model?

Tags: php, string, laravel, eloquent, tinymce

I've a database column named `description` in which i've saved input from tinymce editor. data is something like this,

```
<p><strong>Paragliding </strong></p>
<p>Paragliding is the recreational and competitive adventure sport of flying paragliders: lightweight, free-flying, foot-launched glider aircraft with no rigid primary structure. The pilot sits in a harness suspended below a fabric wing.<br /> </p>
```

I can easily display the data in view with following,

```
{{$data->description}} or {!! $data->description !!}
```

But, I need some processing to get 30 words from text with following code in model,

```
/**
 * @param $sentence
 * @param int $count
 * @return mixed
 */
function get_words($sentence, $count = 30) {
    preg_match("/(?:\w+(?:\W+|$)){0,$count}/", $sentence, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

/**
 * @return short_description
 */
public function shortDescription()
{
    return $this->get_words($this->description);
}
```

and I'm currently geting empty when I call `shortDescription` function.

Is there any way to get plain text from `$this->description` variable ?

Any suggestion help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use strip_tags() php function for get only text,

```
$text = "<p><strong>Paragliding </strong></p>
<p>Paragliding is the recreational and competitive adventure sport of flying paragliders: lightweight, free-flying, foot-launched glider aircraft with no rigid primary structure. The pilot sits in a harness suspended below a fabric wing.<br /> </p>";
$plainText = strip_tags($text);
```

output,

> "Paragliding Paragliding is the recreational and competitive adventure
> sport of flying paragliders: lightweight, free-flying, foot-launched
> glider aircraft with no rigid primary structure. The pilot sits in a
> harness suspended below a fabric wing. "

further details you can see, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
/**
 * @return short_description
 */
public function getShortDescriptionAttribute()
{
    $taglessDescription = strip_tags($this->description);
    return Str::words($taglessDescription, 30, '....');
}
```

**Blade File**

```
{{ $data->short_description }}
```

Comment: let me try at first

Comment: I'm stucked here for a while :D, Now i get it right

Answer (score 0):

```
{{strip_tags(Illuminate\Support\Str::words($item->description,30))}}
//this will print 30 words

{!! html_entity_decode($data->description) !!}
//this will print with html
```

or

```
{strip_tags($data->description)}
 //this will strip your HTML tags

{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($data->description,30)}} // this will print 30 character with 3 dots default
```

In version 5.8+ str helpers got removed you must use `Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($string)` instead `str_limit` or `install composer require laravel/helpers` to use this

```
{{substr(strip_tags($item->description),0,5)}} //this will print 30 character

{{strip_tags(Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($item->description,30))}} //this will print 30 character

{{strip_tags(Illuminate\Support\Str::words($item->description,30))}} //this will print 30 words
```

here you can get all helpers of string
[laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#strings-method-list)